# Get global variables out of blackjack game

Tags: python, blackjack

I am trying to make a game of blackjack and I am having significant trouble with the global variables of the players hand, dealers hand, and bet to reset or clear after a completed hand so a new hand can be played.  How can I get rid of these global variables while referencing these variables in multiple functions?

```
import os
import random
import sys

d = []
p = []
c = input("How many chips do you want: ")
chips = int(c)
b = input("Place your bet: ")
bet = int(b)


def card(x):
    x.append(random.randint(1, 11))


def clear():
    os.system("clear")


def main():
    global p
    global d
    card(p)
    card(p)
    card(d)
    card(d)
    show1()
    check()

    answer = input("Play again? y or n: ")
    if answer == "y":
        bb = list(b)
        bb.clear()
        bet.clear()
        p.clear()
        d.clear()
        main()
    else:
        sys.exit(0)


def show1():
    global d
    global p
    print(str(d[0]) + " []")


print(p)


def show2():

    global d
    global p
    print(d)
    print(p)


def win():
    print("You win")
    chip = chips
    bett = bet
    stash = chip + bett
    print(stash)


def lose():
    print("You lose")
    chip = chips
    bett = bet
    stash = chip - bett
    print(stash)


def check2():
    global p
    global d
    dealer = sum(d)
    player = sum(p)

    if player == 21:
        win()
    elif player > 21:
        lose()
    elif dealer > 21:
        win()
    elif dealer == 21:
        lose()
    elif dealer > player:
        lose()
    else:
        win()


def check():

    global d
    global p

    while sum(p) < 21:
        player = sum(p)
        dealer = sum(d)
        choice = input("Hit or stay? Type h or s: ")

        if choice == "h":
            clear()
            card(p)
            show1()
        elif player >= 21:
            break
        else:
            break

    while sum(d) < sum(p):
        dealer = sum(d)
        player = sum(p)
        card(d)
        clear()
        show2()

        if dealer > player:
            break
        elif dealer >= 21:
            break
        else:
            check2()


main()
```

Comment: You could utilise [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) to contain and get access to your game-related functions, which will allow you to keep things together more logically.

Comment: There's too much vertical space here. I also ran your code through the `black` formatter so that it's readable.

Comment: Also, this is probably better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: A starting point is to put all your global state into a class called `Game` or `GameState`. Then, all your other methods either accept `GameState` as a parameter or are member functions of `Game`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at Scopes in python again [Scopes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-resolution-in-python-legb-rule/). In your given code you don't need ANY `global` Identifier at all (you should try to avoid them anyway, so good for you). Just getting rid of all the lines with `global` in them will work perfectly fine.

I tried running your code, and it seems that you are making some weird desitions structure-wise. If I would be you, I would sit down again, and get your Structure ( what function calls which method, when does this happen...)`correct, because as fas as I have seen, you are making some poor desitions.

Just one quick example. When you get asked if you want to "stay" or "hit" and you choose to "stay" it causes a loop and the player loses control over his cards.
Another example would be the

```
    if choice == "h":
        clear()
        card(p)
        show1()
    elif player >= 21:
        break
    else:
        break
```

structure. your `elif` and `else` do the same thing, so why do you have both, in that case just get rid of the `elif`-statement.

One more thing would be, to use `os._exit(1)` instead of `sys.exit(0)`. `sys.exit(0)` will throw some sort of a warning and your program will not close the way you want it too.